# Check if gcloud SQL instance exists

Tags: bash, gcloud

I have to delete a SQL instance if it exists. Else skip it.

I tried `gcloud sql instances list --filter name=dev-foo`

This returns

```
NAME                  DATABASE_VERSION  LOCATION       TIER              PRIMARY_ADDRESS  PRIVATE_ADDRESS  STATUS
dev-foo               POSTGRES_14       us-central1-a  db-custom-1-1234  1.2.3.4          -                RUNNABLE
```

Adding linux commands here

`gcloud sql instances list --filter name=dev-kansal3-811a8004 | wc -l | xargs`

`wc -l` has leading whitespace and returns `2` as output, `xargs` is used to remove whitespace. I need 1 as output not 2. Can someone help here?

Also, when SQL instance `dev-foo` doesn't exist. This command outputs

```
Listed 0 items.
0
```

Is there a way to avoid getting `Listed 0 items.`?

Comment: `gcloud sql instances list  --uri`  just outputs the first line if there are no instances.  Be aware that after deleting a sql instance you can't create a new one with the same name for one week.

Comment: Thanks @intotecho. This is helpful but if the instance doesn't exist, it still outputs `Listed 0 items.` If I check with `wc -l` both will give 1 as output. Do you know a way to suppress `Listed 0 items.`?

Comment: @mayankb I shared a solution, can you let me know whether it is worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`--no-user-output-enabled`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--user-output-enabled) flag with `gcloud` command to skip `Listed 0 items`

For Example:

```
gcloud sql instances list --no-user-output-enabled
```

Or you can use with

```
gcloud sql instances list --uri --no-user-output-enabled
```

As suggested by @intotecho

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. This is a good answer but I checked `Listed 0 items.` was coming as STDERR and just did 2</dev/null. For capturing output I used `sed` and removed the header row and then counted the output.